# Weird question marks getting entered in tkinter entry when function keys are pressed

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am coding an application that sends entries to a database. I use `tkinter.Entry` for getting user input. When I press the function keys a weird question mark appears in the entry and python treats it as a character on my mac. While I used it on windows I didn't get the question marks. I also restarted my mac but it doesn't help.

[image: An image of the 'question mark']

Comment: Means invalid character I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround for it.

1. Create a function that returns "break" when function keys are pressed.

```py
 def validate(event):
     keys = ['F1', 'F2', 'F3', 'F4', 'F5', 'F6', 'F7', 'F8', 'F9', 'F10', 'F11', 'F12']
     for i in keys:
         if i == event.keysym:
             return 'break'
```

2. Now bind the entries to the validate function

```py
sample_entry.bind('<KeyPress>', validate)
```

This skips the `KeyPress` when the function keys are pressed.

Comment: Can you please fix up the code? This wouldn't work as is; there's at least a syntax and name error.

Comment: It does work. This is the code I use in my program.  I just copy pasted it here.

Comment: The indentation is *definitely* broken; it cannot work. What is ˋeˋ? You might be pulling it in as a closure in your real code, but here it is just undefined.

Comment: The ``keys = ...`` is on the same indentation level as ``def ...``. That's *not* correct.

Comment: Fixed the indentation issue. Thanks for the clarification.